# Issues with df.to_excel possibly due to either Pandas as a platform or because I have a mac. Any workarounds?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, macos

Disclaimer: I am new to programming and this is my first project, so if this is really obvious I apologize.

So I am running through some data that I have successfully web scraped and made into a Pandas DataFrame. The data is currently being separated at the moment into 6 different CSV files (There are 6 different measures, so each person's measures are being put into the respective measures) with f" Dates : {IDname}" and f"Scores : {IDname} as the column names.

I would like to, instead, separate them into different sheets within an excel file so each person can have their own sheet inside each event. This will make it easier to store data later, because I can just save the results (the slope of their graph, their graph, ect) under their personal sheet. Also, putting it on a CSV file will require an extra step to format it correctly, so this would be more efficient.

So here is where the issue arises. This is what I have so far. It worked once for whatever reason, but every other time I have been getting BadZipFile: file is not a zip file.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine = 'openpyxl', mode = 'a') as writer:
       df.to_excel(writer, sheet = idname)
```

here are a couple of other things I have tried.

```
 wb = Workbook()
 ws = wb.active
 for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index = True, header = True):
     ws.append(r)
 for cell in ws['A'] + ws[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'
    wb.save(filename)
```

---

```
df.to_excel(writer, index = False, header = False, startrow= (cols + 1))
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
reader = pd.read_excel(r(filename))
        writer.save()
        df.to_excel(writer, index = False, header = False, startrow = (len(reader) + 1)
```

--
I have read in other places that the issue with the top code can be fixed if you go in and save the file on its own and then run the program, but because I am on a Mac, I can not open an XLSX file to do so. Is there any work around? Is there a way I can reference to .numbers instead, maybe? Perhaps I should just find Excel from a third party?

Thanks